# How to retrieve a Firebase DatabaseReference for child with specific children child values?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Firebase usage  with Android development and I've been stuck on this issue. Everything is working fine and I'm able to successfully display users i a RecyclerView with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, **but** here's my issue, I *only* want to display users whom their *requestStatus* is set to "true", not *all* the users. Tried searching for this to no avail.

This is my Firebase realtime database.

[image]

Calling the database in onCreateView and setting the adapter

```
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")

    val clientsRecycler = binding.clientsRecycler

    val options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
        .setQuery(database, User::class.java)
        .build()

    adapter = Adapter(options)
    clientsRecycler.adapter = adapter
```

My adapter class

```
class Adapter(options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User>) :
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, Adapter.ClientsViewHolder>(options) {

class ClientsViewHolder(private val binding: ClientItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    val name = binding.clientName
    val phone = binding.clientPhone
    val location = binding.clientLocation
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ClientsViewHolder {
    return ClientsViewHolder(ClientItemBinding
        .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ClientsViewHolder, position: Int, model: User) {
    holder.name.text = model.name
    holder.phone.text = model.phone
    holder.location.text = model.location
}}
```

How can I only display John (whom's requestStatus is set to true) and not Robert?

I'm guessing the solution has got to do with FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users") but I'm just not sure how can I tell Firebase that I only want users with "true" requestStatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Change

> ```
>     val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
> ```

to

```
        var filterQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("requestStatus").equalTo("true")
```

and

```
        val options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
        .setQuery(database, User::class.java)
        .build()
```

to

```
     val options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
        .setQuery(filterQuery, User::class.java)
        .build()
```

Basically instead of using a DatabaseReference just create a query and then pass it to setQuery()